# How to properly convey non-Latin words in a practical Latin text?

Tags: contemporary-latin, new-latin, modern-life

My question here is firmly in regards to contemporary Latin, in the sense of Latin to be used not as a dead language (in other words, I am not looking for a Nosoponian answer that invalidates anything made after Cicero) but as a regular form of correspondence and writing in a dynamic world. How should one go about writing about things that do not have an immediate translation into Latin? I will give examples:

If I wanted to talk about, say, a company like SpaceX, how should I go about calling it? My first instinct is that, for clarity, I should simply call it SpaceX without changing anything and adding maybe a word beside it to help with conjugation, like *societas* (which the Morgan And Silva Furman University Lexicon states is the appropriate word to use for company). So I would say *Amicus meus in Societate SpaceX laborat*. But I am not sure if this is the best approach or if there is a better one that you might know of. Any suggestion is appreciated.

If I wanted to talk about a person with a surname that could be easily converted to a Latinized format (for example, a latin-based surname like President Jair Bolsonaro's) should I Latinise the entire name, writing *Iairus Bolsonarus* or should I only latinize the first name (*Iairus Bolsonaro*), and most importantly, why? In the case for *Iairus Bolsonaro*, this is the standards defended by Vicipaedia. But I have yet to see a good argument in favor of this other than it makes it easier for searching on the web. But since my objective is for using Latin in day-to-day writing, I am not sure if it is right to keep surnames that can clearly be Latinized in their original form.

If I wanted to talk about a person who's surname is very different from what one would expect in Latin, what should I do then? Here I see a fork in the road. It seems proper to simply change the name into something more in line with Latin simply because it makes talking about said person clearer and easier and one can easily adapt to the change of the name. For example, by calling a Hermann *Armanius*. But I also must admit and take into consideration that this would affect and remove from *clarity*, which should be considered as much as practicality. In which case, what do you suggest one should do?

This is what I can think of out of the top of my head, but if any of you have any other further musings on how to implement an effective use of Latin in a way that is both clear and practical, please tell me what rules you follow!